# Python PyQt5 how to change minimized icon

Tags: python, icons, pyqt5, python-3.6, pyinstaller

I converted a Python script to an executable (`.exe`) via PyInstaller. I would like to change minimized icon (See the picture below)

[image: minimized icon on the bar]
I searched for it but couldn't find a solution in PyQt5 nor PyInstaller.

How can I change that symbol to a .png or .ico that I choose? Is there a command like `--icon ico.png` in PyInstaller for minimized icon?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the pyinstaller on a .spec file. Best way to create a .spec file is to run the installer on your main py file, it will spit out a .spec file.

Inside the .spec file, in the EXE tuple, you need to include `icon='c:\\app\\icon.ico'`

'icon.ico' as your icon file.

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller is not responsible for minimized icon, which should be set by code in your main window. like this,

```
setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('mainwindow.ico'))
```

By this code, your main window icon and minimized window icon will be set as "mainwindow.ico".

Note, "mainwindow.ico" should be put under same path of your main window  .py file, or else you need to replace it with a relative path where your ico file is stored.